# Implementing dry-run in ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash, dry

anybody know how to implement dry-run option in Ruby?

I need something like this, but only for ruby
https://serverfault.com/questions/147628/implementing-dry-run-in-bash-scripts

I've tried this, but part after else doesn't work:

```
DRY_RUN = true

def perform(*args)
  command = args
  if DRY_RUN
    command.each{|x| puts x}
  else
   command.each {|x| x}
  end
end

perform("puts 'Hello'")
```

Thanks for any idea in advance.

P.S I don't want use something like system`("ruby -e \"puts 'Hello'\"")`

Comment: In the else branch, you probably want something like `command.each {|x| puts x; eval x}`

Comment: Yes, thank you! It works pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help:

```
def perform(*commands)
  commands.each { |x| DRY_RUN ? puts(x) : eval(x)}
end
```

It results in:

```
DRY_RUN = true
perform("puts 'Hello'")
```

> puts 'Hello'
>
> => ["puts 'Hello'"]

```
DRY_RUN = false
perform("puts 'Hello'")
```

> Hello
>
> => ["puts 'Hello'"]

Comment: Yes, with "eval" it works properly, thank you a lot @Maxim for your reply!